# Why is the Items class in Scrapy stored in a separate file?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm quite new to scrapy and pythonic programming - so I guess this question is more a noob question:

Why do we have a separate file (items.py) to store the items class in, if we could also just include it in the spider file (or can't we?) ?

Is it just to create a better structure? Are there any Python principles to structuring a project that I could study?

Answer (score 1):

The `items.py` file is a separate file so as to separate concerns similar to the `pipelines.py` and `middlewares.py` files. Separating the files like that makes for a better structured project and follows good programming guidelines.

You can however put everything in the spider class and it will still run fine but the code may quickly become unmaintaianble.